# Checking if a Set inside another Set contains an object

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a datamodel that is similar to this:

```
class User { public long id; }
class UserGroup { public Set<User> members; }
class UserGroupAccess { public String access; public UserGroup userGroup; }

class Document {
  public User owner;
  public String publicAccess;
  public Set<UserGroupAccess> userGroupAccessses;
}
```

And the logic goes as this:

```
1. If owner = user then allow access
2. If publicAccess ilike r% allow access
3. If on of the userGroupAccesses have access ilike r%
    AND the user is in the userGroup attached to it, then allow access
```

My current query is:

```
criteria.createAlias( "userGroupAccesses", "u" );
Disjunction root = Restrictions.disjunction();
root.add( Restrictions.ilike( "publicAccess", "r%" ) );
root.add( Restrictions.eq( "owner", currentUser ) );

Conjunction ugAccess = Restrictions.conjunction();
ugAccess.add( Restrictions.ilike( "u.access", "r%" ) );
root.add( ugAccess );

criteria.add( root );
```

And this gives me almost what I want, expect the check if the userGroup attached to u contains the currentUser.

I've been trying different approaches, like:

```
criteria.createAlias( "u.userGroup.members", "member" );
ugAccess.add( Restrictions.eq("member", currentUser) );
```

But this doesn't work.

Any ideas what I should be looking into here?

Update:
Using the approach outlined from JB Nizet, I got this:

```
criteria.createAlias( "userGroupAccesses", "u" );
criteria.createAlias( "u.userGroup", "ug" );
criteria.createAlias( "ug.members", "member" );

Disjunction root = Restrictions.disjunction();
root.add( Restrictions.ilike( "publicAccess", "r%" ) );
root.add( Restrictions.eq( "user", currentUser ) );

Conjunction ugAccess = Restrictions.conjunction();
ugAccess.add( Restrictions.ilike( "u.access", "r%" ) );
ugAccess.add( Restrictions.eq( "member.uid", currentUser.getUid() ) );
root.add( ugAccess );

criteria.add( root );
```

And this seemed to work, but it actually removed the two first parts of the or, so it ONLY applies whats inside the conjunction.

What would be the correct approach here? do I need to split into sub-queries?

Solved:

```
criteria.createAlias( "userGroupAccesses", "u", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN );
criteria.createAlias( "u.userGroup", "ug", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN );
criteria.createAlias( "ug.members", "member", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't chain properties like this in a Criteria query. Try

```
criteria.createAlias("u.userGroup", "userGroup");
criteria.createAlias("userGroup.members", "member");
ugAccess.add(Restrictions.eq("member", currentUser));
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried something like that also. But I keep getting "Exception (org.hibernate.QueryException): could not resolve property: member of: Document".

Comment: It seems to be working now, had to use Restrictions.eq("member.id",currentUser.id), not sure why.